# Excel formula keeps reverting to the original UDF name

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, vba

I made a UDF called "GetField" and made a spreadsheet that called it 384 times. Then the boss noted that, in keeping with Excel's own styles, that should really be GETFIELD. So I changed it. But now I can't change the formulas *in the sheet* to use the new version of the name.

If I click in the field and delete the "d", Excel displays the pop-up with the possible hits, including GETFIELD. If I select that, I can see the editor change it to GETFIELD, but if I return to that field it's changed it back to GetField again. I tried several variations on the theme, including using Search/Replace and re-typing the whole thing, but every time it reverts to the original camel-cased name.

Does anyone know a way to get Excel to update the name?

Comment: Try using Find And Replace. There are "Options" where you can select "Match Case". You might have luck there. You may want to propose that you do all lower case to distinguish UDFs from built in functions too... ;)

Comment: I did try that. It helpfully finds and replaces all 384 instances... which then immediately turn back into "GetField" again!

Comment: Excel doesn't care about upper/lower cases in function names therefore both should work anyway. But to change a solution is to rename the UDF in VBA to something different like `XXDD` and then use replace to change `GetField` into `XXDD` then rename the UDF to `GETFIELD` and replace `XXDD` to `GETFIELD`. This should work.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - ok let me try that!

Comment: Worked like a champ, if you make that an answer I'll upvote it!

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Nice solution. Definitely worth posting as an answer for future users to refer to.

Comment: @dwirony that solution looked too obvious to me, didn't expect that impact. But you are right, I posted an answer for future readers.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I've had the exact same problem in the past where I've had to use a placeholder, but it took me a bit to realize what was going on - I don't think I've seen that placeholder solution posted on here before so I figure it's a nice addition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Excel doesn't care about upper/lower case in function names, therefore both should work no matter what case your UDF has.

But to have it nicely and consistent you can force Excel to a specific upper/lower case change by renaming the UDF to any other name first.

So for Example your original UDF name is `GetField` and you want to rename it to `GETFIELD`:

1. Rename your UDF in VBA from `GetField` to something else like `MyTempName`
2. Find/Replace all formulas from `GetField` to `MyTempName`
3. Rename your UDF in VBA from `MyTempName` to `GETFIELD`
4. Find/Replace all formulas from `MyTempName` to `GETFIELD`

Answer (score 0):

In the VBA IDE check that there isn't a duplicate of the function with the old name such as in the personal xlsb library.